# How to obtain address of other program memory and then read it in my program

Tags: c#, memory, reverse-engineering

I'd want to find an address of where other program (`other.exe`) is storing some specific value

and then read it from my program (C#), but I don't really understand how can I achieve that

I tried finding it with CheatEngine, and I managed to find that value under two addresses, so e.g `0x048907B0`

[image]

Now I tried to add this particular address to base address of the process, but the returned value is just chaos, nothing even close to my value

What I'm doing wrong here?

Previously I've seen some "proved" approach where there was "xor" involved, basically you had to read some "xor" value with known "xor address" and then in order to read other values, the formula was

```
info.MyValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0) ^ xor;
```

Thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();

if (process == null)
{
    throw new Exception($"Process with name: '{processName}' is not running");
}

var mc = new MemoryContext(process);
```

---

```
public class MemoryContext
{
    const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    private int baseAddress;
    private Process _process;
    private IntPtr handle;

    public MemoryContext(Process process)
    {
        _process = process;
        baseAddress = _process.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
        handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, _process.Id);
    }
    
    public ProcessDetails RefreshData()
    {
        var info = new ProcessDetails();

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];

        // here I'm trying to read that value
        ReadProcessMemory((int)handle, 0x048907B0 + baseAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
        info.MyValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        
        return info;
    }
}
```

Comment: That value shouldn't have to be added to the base address; does it work otherwise? As far as finding the address every time, if you follow Cheat Engine's tutorials it should show you how to find a reliable chain of pointers to some dynamically allocated data's address. You then just have to do the pointer logic in your program to get the final address out.

Comment: @RandomDavis I managed to find it in CE, but what do you actually mean by "pointer logic"?

Comment: Oh, I removed `+ baseAddress` and I got the value, thanks!

Comment: By "pointer logic" I mean the whole business of starting from a static address that's a pointer, then following some chain of pointers and offsets to end up at a final address. If that's all new to you, then definitely do the tutorial and some more research on pointers. That way you won't have to run Cheat Engine every time to get the address(es).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this as a comment, but since it worked I'll post it as an answer.

When you find the address of your data in Cheat Engine, the address it gives you is already the correct one. So, to read the correct address, instead of `0x048907B0 + baseAddress`, you can simply put in `0x048907B0` and it should work.